# Is there a way to replace a field used in multiple reports?

Tags: rename-symbol

In our Salesforce application we have a checkbox field `Paid__c` which is used by a very large number of reports for filters etc.

We need to change this field to a Formula (Checkbox) type based on a different record. There isn't a way (that I know of) to Edit the existing field and change it to a formula.

If we delete the checkbox field and re-create it (with the same name) as a Formula (Checkbox), will all the reports still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you delete a field, it is no longer available to the report(s)
- If you add a new field, all of the reports have to be updated to include that field in the displayed column and/or filter(s)

**Mass updating reports**

One approach is to download the report metadata into your IDE (VsCode, Illuminated Cloud 2, etc) and mass edit the XML, then redeploy